# ROS support to onrobot HEX-E QC

Tags: ros

I’m currently working on integrating a Hex-E QC force-torque sensor into my ROS-based robotic system. While researching, I came across the ros2_net_ft_driver GitHub repository (https://github.com/gbartyzel/ros2_net_ft_driver), where it mentions testing with the OnRobot HEX-E V2.

My specific question is whether the driver mentioned in the repository is expected to work seamlessly with the OnRobot Hex-E QC version. I’ve reviewed the documentation, but I want to confirm with the community if anyone has experience using this driver with the Hex-E QC model.

If anyone has successfully integrated the Hex-E QC force-torque sensor with ROS or has insights into its compatibility, I would greatly appreciate your guidance. Additionally, if there are alternative drivers or packages that are recommended for the Hex-E QC, I’d love to hear about them.

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.